# Proof: If $x$ is odd, then $x+2$ is odd.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm fairly new to writing proofs so any advice can help.

I'm asked to prove the following statement: "If $x$ is odd, then $x+2$ is odd". Here is my proof:

We will prove this by contraposition: if $x+2$ is not odd, then $x$ is not odd.

Let there be an integer $k$ such that $x+2 = 2k$.

Thus,
\begin{align}
x & = 2k-2 \\
 & = 2(k-1)
\end{align}

Then $x = 2(k-1)$ is an even number.

Since the contrapositive is true, the statement "If $x$ is odd, then $x+2$ is odd" is true by logical equivalency.

---

The problem is: I don't know if my proof is *enough* or how to properly tackle them. Any advice?

Comment: What is your definition of *odd* ?

Comment: Think about this: can a number be neither odd or even?

Answer (score 3):

This seems fine as long as you know that "not odd" is the same as even for integers. Also, for your opening sentence in the proof, I might say "If $x+2$ is even then we can write $x+2=2k$ for some integer $k$."

You can also just prove this directly if you know that odd integers are of the form $2k+1$. That is, if $x=2k+1$, then $x+2=2(k+1)+1$.

Comment: It might also worth mentioning that if $k$ is an integer, then $k + 1$ (or $k - 1$) is also an integer, to complete the logical step.

Answer (score 0):

An integer $m$ is *even* if and only $2 \mid m$; otherwise, $m$ is *odd*.

If $x + 2$ is even, then

$2 \mid x + 2; \tag 1$

clearly,

$2 \mid 2; \tag 2$

thus

$2 \mid (x + 2) - 2 = x; \tag 3$

that is, $x$ is even, contrary to hypothesis; thus, $x + 2$ cannot be even, hence it is odd.

By the way, our OP's proof, being essentially the same as mine, is fine.